# How to make the linux filesystem power failure safe?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, debian, embedded-linux

I need to have a robust filesystem on an debian or ubuntu linux. The problem is, that the system can be "shutdown" by just cut the power ( without a real shutdown ). 
After such a scenario I don't want to have the filesystem check or corrupted data on the root filesystem. I need to make sure that the system starts without problems again the next time. What could be the solution?

Comment: Which filesystem?... Journalled ones, that most linuxes now use, are (pretty) safe on their own.

Comment: *"After such a scenario I don't want to have the filesystem check ..."* -- The only way to avoid filesystem corruption would be to have backup or failsafe power.  Otherwise use a journaled fs that can try to recover (i.e. repair itself) from a dirty shutdowm.

Comment: If you have sufficient RAM and are OK with changes to the rootfs not persisting past reboots, you can try running with a read-only rootfs. There are things that need to be read-write, typically /tmp, /etc and /var. You can either install unionfs and mount a tmpfs over the rootfs or mangle the startup scripts to mount these on tmpfs and copy over the original contents on boot.

Answer (score 0):

Along with journaling , Soft Updates can also be a method.Regardless of the method you use, please keep in mind that these methods can only guarantee you the consistency of the file system and neither of them can guarantee the safety of your data.Disk can be mounted more quickly in case of soft updates.